# Why does Cytoscape go into an "infinite" loop in this specific situation?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

If I clone a layout configuration with `Object.assign` and try to use that layout, cytoscape quickly causes an out of memory error.  I can work around this by just defining a second layout mostly identical to the first and not cloning, but I am interested to know the reason behind the problem, or if it's a possible bug in cytoscape.

With this example code, click `add and layout 2` right after loading the page and it will hang/run out of memory.  (Have your task manager handy to kill your tab or browser.)  Different combinations of adding nodes and running the cloned layout will mostly hang, but not always.

```js
let cy
const layout1 = {
  name: 'euler',
  springLength: edge => 80,
  mass: node => 4,
  randomize: true,
  animate: false,
  gravity: -1.2,
  maxIterations: 1000,
  maxSimulationTime: 4000,
}

const layout2 = Object.assign({}, layout1, {
  fit: false,
  animate: true,
  randomize: false,
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    layout: layout1,
    style: [
      {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          label: 'data(id)',
        },
      },
    ],
    elements: [
      { data: { id: 'a' } },
      { data: { id: 'b' } },
      { data: { id: 'a_b', source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
    ],
  })
})

function add() {
  cy.add([
    { data: { id: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'd' } },
    { data: { id: 'c_d', source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
  ])
  // cy.layout(layout2).run()
}

function doLayout1() {
  cy.layout(layout1).run()
}

function doLayout2() {
  cy.layout(layout2).run()
}

function addAndLayout2() {
  add()
  doLayout2()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.5.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-euler@1.2.1/cytoscape-euler.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    
      <style>
        body {
          height: 100%;
        }
        #cy {
          height: 100%;
          flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .main {
          height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
        }
      </style>
    
      <body>
        <button onclick="add()">add nodes</button>
        <button onclick="doLayout1()">layout 1</button>
        <button onclick="doLayout2()">layout 2</button>
        <button onclick="addAndLayout2()">add and layout 2</button>
        <div class="main">
          <div id="cy"></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Ojbect.assign` (even if you did not copy the object properly, it should not hang).

The reason is the `randomize` option. For this particular graph, when the randomize option is set to `false`, the layout never ends. Just remove `randomize: false` from the second layout, or after adding the new nodes and before running `layout2`, run the `random` layout (or just randomize the nodes manually) -- the `layout2` will terminate.

The problem is that: the layout must terminate at some point (in the worst case when the  umber of max iterations is reached). But this particular layout  never terminates.

The interesting thing is that this simple graph turns out to be one of the worst cases for some other layout algorithms as well (for `randomized: false`). I tried `cose-bilkent`. It also takes a little bit longer and terminates when the maximum number of iterations is reached (setting `numIter` option to lower number will result in early termination, worse quality) -- but the result is really bad.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I made a false association on the `Object.assign`, that helps a ton!

I wonder if the `randomized` is required, or is it that the nodes overlap exactly, so it makes the physics simulation fail?  I'll try testing that theory, but I wondered what your thoughts were.

Comment: What do you mean by "`randomized` is required"? If it was required to be `true`, then it wouldn't be an option. When the randomized is `false` an incremental layout is applied -- the current node positions are used as the initial position in the layout algorithm. This is good for keeping the user's mental map. When it is true, initially random points are assigned to nodes and then the layout algorithm is executed. It is not necessarily the overlap, it is the overall state of the positions of the nodes (even if you just add node `c` in add function, it never terminates).

Comment: In any case, the layout *must* terminate. Either when it converges, or the maximum number of iterations is reached. Maybe, you can report it as an issue.

Comment: I mean that with `randomize: false`, the layout fails, so it seems to be implicitly required to be `true`.  I get that the layout has to settle/terminate somehow, but in this case it's clearly not.